# How can I use parallel loop in MATLAB CPSO

Tags: performance, matlab

I want to implement parallel Clustering Particle Swarm Optimisation (CPSO) MATLAB [using `parfor` loop](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) but it is taking more elapsed time than using simple `for` loops.

So please help me execute parallel loop iterations in my code.

I have MATLAB R2013a and Intel core i3 processor.

```
matlabpool('open', 2)  

tic;  

for iteration=1:iterations  

%CALCULATE EUCLIDEAN DISTANCES TO ALL CENTROIDS
distances=zeros(dataset_size(1),centroids,particles);

for particle=1:particles
    for centroid=1:centroids
        distance=zeros(dataset_size(1),1);
        for data_vector=1:dataset_size(1)
            %meas(data_vector,:)
            distance(data_vector,1)=norm(swarm_pos(centroid,:,particle)-meas(data_vector,:));

        end
        distances(:,centroid,particle)=distance;
    end
end
                %fprintf('\nEnd, meas(dv) is %5.4f\n',meas(data_vector,:));

%ASSIGN MEASURES with CLUSTERS    
for particle=1:particles
    [value, index] = min(distances(:,:,particle),[],2);
    c(:,particle) = index;
end

% PLOT STUFF... CLEAR HANDLERS
delete(pc); delete(txt);
pc = []; txt = [];

% PLOT STUFF...
hold on;
for particle=1:particles
    for centroid=1:centroids
        if any(c(:,particle) == centroid)
            if dimensions == 3
                pc = [pc plot3(swarm_pos(centroid,1,particle),swarm_pos(centroid,2,particle),swarm_pos(centroid,3,particle),'*','color',cluster_colors_vector(particle,:))];
            elseif dimensions == 2
                pc = [pc plot(swarm_pos(centroid,1,particle),swarm_pos(centroid,2,particle),'*','color',cluster_colors_vector(particle,:))];
            end
        end
    end
end
set(pc,{'MarkerSize'},{12})
hold off;

%CALCULATE GLOBAL FITNESS and LOCAL FITNESS:=swarm_fitness
average_fitness = zeros(particles,1);
for particle=1:particles
    for centroid = 1 : centroids
        if any(c(:,particle) == centroid)
            local_fitness=mean(distances(c(:,particle)==centroid,centroid,particle));
            average_fitness(particle,1) = average_fitness(particle,1) + local_fitness;
        end
    end
    average_fitness(particle,1) = average_fitness(particle,1) / centroids;
    if (average_fitness(particle,1) < swarm_fitness(particle))
        swarm_fitness(particle) = average_fitness(particle,1);
        swarm_best(:,:,particle) = swarm_pos(:,:,particle);     %LOCAL BEST FITNESS
    end
end    
[global_fitness, index] = min(swarm_fitness);       %GLOBAL BEST FITNESS
swarm_overall_pose = swarm_pos(:,:,index);          %GLOBAL BEST POSITION
            fprintf('global position is %5.4f\n',swarm_overall_pose);            

% SOME INFO ON THE COMMAND WINDOW
fprintf('%3d. global fitness is %5.4f\n',iteration,global_fitness);            
%uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[40 20 180 20],'String',sprintf('Actual fitness is: %5.4f', global_fitness),'BackgroundColor',get(gcf,'Color'));        
pause(simtime);



% SAMPLE r1 AND r2 FROM UNIFORM DISTRIBUTION [0..1]
r1 = rand;
r2 = rand;

% UPDATE CLUSTER CENTROIDS
%p = Par(50); 
for particle=1:particles 

    inertia = w * swarm_vel(:,:,particle);
    cognitive = c1 * r1 * (swarm_best(:,:,particle)-swarm_pos(:,:,particle));
    social = c2 * r2 * (swarm_overall_pose-swarm_pos(:,:,particle));
    vel = inertia+cognitive+social;

    swarm_pos(:,:,particle) = swarm_pos(:,:,particle) + vel ;   % UPDATE PARTICLE POSE
    swarm_vel(:,:,particle) = vel;                              % UPDATE PARTICLE VEL

end
%stop(p);
%plot(p); 
% telapsed = toc(tstart);
%     minTime = min(telapsed,minTime);  
end
```

Comment: Show what you have already tried and what are the errors or problems you are facing .

Comment: I have tried MATLAB code of PSO clustering using fisheriris dataset.now when i am using parfor loops instead of for loops then it is giving degraded performance in terms of elapsed time.

Comment: You will need to provide more information.  For instance, your `parpool` configuration.

Comment: Please see the part of code, i have added matlabpool('open', 2). this is serial code and is taking around 4 seconds but if i use parfor loop then time is increasing with increase in parfor loops.why is it so?

Comment: What about a minimal example that shows the behavior. I guess it is because of excessive data shuffling.

Comment: when i replace some for loops by parfor loop then it gives error message to slice the variables...i think this is the main problem because unsliced variables are creating overburden on matlab workers and hence time is increasing.